# Different values for each subclass

Tags: java, class, static, subclass

I would like to create a school(Houses) with 4 subclasses that take a basic values from the superclass(color, logo etc, each subclass with different values) and keep track, each sub class to itself of the number of students and points.
I also want to grant the ability to add points only for instance of Houses directly.
This is the code:

```
public class Houses {
int students = 75;
String color;
String logo;
String Founder;
String Trait;
String name;
int points = 0;
protected void Welcome() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to " + name + "! \n This house was founded by " +
            Founder + " and his core value is " + Trait + " , the house logo is " + logo
            + " and his color is " + color + "\n We have right now " + students + " students and "
            + points + " points. BEST OF LUCK!");
}
public void AddPoints(int x){
    points += x;
    System.out.println(x + " Points added!\nYour house now have " + points + " points");
}}

public class Gryffindor extends Houses {
Gryffindor() {
    name = "Gryffindor";
    students += 1;
    color = "Red";
    logo = "Lion";
    Founder = "Godric Gryffindor";
    Trait = "Brave";
    Welcome();
}}
```

if im making the students and point as static its working fine but of course it add up all the sub classes together.
the best idea is to declare the values students and points inside each subclass as static?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code with an autoformatter and please clarify your question.

Comment: Hey Dmitriy, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a misuse of sub-classes. Unless each sub-class is going to have it's own unique functionality, then each set of data should be associated to an instance of a `House`. You'd then most likely want to use the [Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) to set this data.

**House Class**

```
public class House {
  int students;
  String name;
  String color;
  //Other class variables

  public House(int students, String name, String color) {
    this.students = students;
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
  }

  //Various methods
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class HouseTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    House gryffindor = new House(75, "Gryffindor", "Red");
    House ravenclaw = new House(68, "Ravenclaw", "Blue");
  }
}
```

However, if you *really* want to set this data using a sub-class you can make use of the `House` constuctor via the [super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) keyword which calls the parent constructor. Using the `House` from my code above it would be:

**Gryffindor Class**

```
public class Gryffindor extends House {
  public Gryffindor() {
    super(75, "Gryffindor", "Red");
    //Set value for anything unique to Gryffindor here after super keyword
  }

  //Gryffindor specific methods
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but in this way I need to specify each time the name, color and number of students. I want to add the student to each house and he will get all the characteristics and add one to the sum of students, I also want to keep track of points for each class separately.

Comment: @lupintail That's a misunderstanding of how you would use the `House` object. You would only have this data in the single `House` instance and then each `Student` would have a variable carrying a reference to the `House` they are affiliated with. So your `Student` object would probably have a constructor similar to `Student(String firstName, String lastName, House assignedHouse)` and then your `House` could similarly have an `ArrayList<Student>` variable to track affiliated `Student` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I will use a singleton `School class` to keep a single state count of `students` and `points` throughout the program. So create a class with those values you want to keep a single state track of and make them the class fields.

A singleton is a class that is instantiated once in memory and have the object shared by all classes within the application. This single state object in memory hold single state data points.

```
public class School{
    private int students = 75;
    private int points = 0;
    private static final School instance = new School();

    private School() {}
    
    public static School getInstance() { return instance; }

    public synchronized void addStudent() {
        students++;
    } 

    public synchronized void addPoints(int x) {
        points += x;
    }
  
    public synchronized int getStudents() { return students; }

    public synchronized int getPoints() { return points; }
}
```

So your House class will look like:

```
public class Houses {
School school = School.getInstance();
int students = school.getStudents();
String color;
String logo;
String Founder;
String Trait;
String name;
int points = school.getPoints();

protected void Welcome() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to " + name + "! \n This house was founded by " +
            Founder + " and his core value is " + Trait + " , the house logo is " + logo
            + " and his color is " + color + "\n We have right now " + students + " students and "
            + points + " points. BEST OF LUCK!");
}
public void AddPoints(int x){
    school.addPoints(x);
    System.out.println(x + " Points added!\nYour house now have " + points + " points");
}}
```

And your Gryffindor class

```
public class Gryffindor extends Houses {
Gryffindor() {
    name = "Gryffindor";
    school.addStudent();
    color = "Red";
    logo = "Lion";
    Founder = "Godric Gryffindor";
    Trait = "Brave";
    Welcome();
}}
```

Comment: Thank you! work fine, only problem when im using AddPoints in the message i get "Your house have 0 points" but when im adding another student the point is ok. Another question, if i want to grant the option to use add point only for instance of Houses, how do i apply it for example on Gryffindor?

Comment: P.S after another check its keeping the sum of students of students and points for each sub class(Gryffindor and Raveclaw have the same points and students)

Comment: I was under the impression that you want the student number and the points to maintain the same state across the subclasses. Is that the aim here? Or you want students and points to be unique per subclass?

Comment: If you want the student and point variables to be unique per subclass then you have to make it private in the House class so they can be hidden from the subclasses. Then you can set unique values of the student and point variables at the subclasses. Bear in mind that Class variables are inherited but cannot be overridden. So a parent class variables are available both to the parent and all its subclasses. Use private access for these variables and use setters and getters to access them per subclass; thus making them unique per class.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!